# Angular 4 + Karma - Unexpected token var

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've just migrated my app from Angular 2 to Angular 4. Before I used Karma for unit tests. After migration I try to run tests using **npm test** (like I did it before). But this time I have compilation error says this
[image]

P.S. **npm start** compiles the app perfectly.

It looks like karma can't recognize TypeScript file for some reasons. What does it mean and what is the possible way to fix it?

Comment: Fixed this issue by excluding preloader.ts file in karma.config.js file

Comment: you should put that as the accepted answer to help others perhaps ;)